# Using sed in alternate line

Tags: linux, sed, text-formatting

I have a file with pattern as below:

```
12345.ABC9998
12345555.abc:ffr.abc-MKDHJKSJJDOKSOKSDCKJODCKJ

12345.ABC9998
12345555.abc:ffr.abc-MKDHJKSJJDOKSOKSDCKJODCKJ
```

I wanted to delete everything before the dash and including the dash itself for each of the second line.

Desire output:

```
12345.ABC9998
MKDHJKSJJDOKSOKSDCKJODCKJ

12345.ABC9998
MKDHJKSJJDOKSOKSDCKJODCKJ
```

I know `sed 's/^[^A-Z]*//' file.txt` can do the thing but it will do for every line. How do I edit it to work only on the line I want(each second line)?

Comment: is your first line (first line to the line containing dash) has any dashes? if not they why not just `s/.*-//` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would remove everything up-to dash in every 2<sup>nd</sup> line:

```
sed '0~2s/.*-//' infile
```

if you mean delete on second lines from lines that followed after `12345.ABC9998` line, then you would do:

```
sed '/^12345.ABC9998$/{n; s/.*-//}' infile
```

if you mean delete on second lines that followed after a line containing `12345.ABC9998` strings, you would do:

```
sed '/12345.ABC9998/{n; s/.*-//}' infile
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to act on lines that contain a dash (in your example, that would seem to be the case), then this should work:

```
sed 's/^.*-//' file.txt
```

It will remove everything up to and including a dash from the beginning of every line. Except that, on lines without a dash, the regular expression will not match, so it will not perform any substitutions and will keep the line as is.

---

If what you want is to apply a transformation only on every second line, then you can use the `sed` command `n` (for "next") to skip a line, still sending it to the output.

This would assume you really want to act on the even lines (in your example, there are blank lines between blocks, I'm assuming those are a copy & paste artifact and your question title of "alternate lines" is actually what you want.)

This command would apply the regular expression to even lines only:

```
sed 'n;s/^[^A-Z]*//' file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, can command it to remove everything before uppercase for every second line. In this way, anything before the dashes and the dashes itself can be removed accordingly.

```
sed -i '0~2s/[^A-Z]*//' file
```